# How can i href a local file using tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, html, css, tampermonkey

I want to replace a site's CSS file URL through href, i know it's possible to reference external links containing css but what about a local file instead?

```
document.querySelector("head > link:nth-child(7)").href = "http://example.com/style.css"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be for the local file to be a *script*, perhaps one that assigns the desired CSS text to a `window` property, which can then be retrieved inside your userscript. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         local
// @match        https://example.com
// @require      file:///C:/local.js
// ==/UserScript==

document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style'))
  .textContent = window.cssTextFromLocal;
```

and

```
// local.js
window.cssTextFromLocal = `
  body {
    background-color: green;
  }
`;
```

[image]

Make sure to [permit local file access](https://www.tampermonkey.net/faq.php#Q204).

Of course, if you want to do this *unconditionally* (on every page load, regardless), there's no need for inter-script communication, and you can insert the `<style>` into the DOM inside `local.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Like all Chrome extensions, Tampermonkey by default is subject to a number of restrictions designed to prevent developers from acting maliciously. If Tampermonkey had unfettered access to your filesystem, userscript authors could easily abuse the permission to steal or modify your data without your knowledge.

The closest thing you could do would be to host a server on your local machine (e.g. with Node.js). This would allow you to provide Tampermonkey with a URL like `localhost/style.css` which would be served locally from your computer. This would only work when you had the server running, though.

Alternatively, you could create your own developer-mode Chrome extension which contains the stylesheet within its `web_accessible_resources` and injects it based on a `DeclarativeContent` rule. This would be bypassing Tampermonkey entirely, though, so it doesn't exactly answer the question.